# Cannot open IBM Cloud Tools Package for macOS because file is "damaged"?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

**does anyone know of a workaround for this issue so I can get up & running?**

I have attempted to download IBM Cloud Tools Package for macOS *(Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers with integrated IBM Bluemix Tools)* from Bluemix but when I try to open it I get a warning message that the file is "damaged" & cannot be opened. I've attached a screenshot of the error.

I'm running on macOS Sierra 10.12.3 (16D32)

Site where downloaded from -> http://eclipse.bluemix.net/packages/epp.bmt/

Cheers,

- Brennan

[Snapshot of "damaged" error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSYm0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try again. I was able to successfully download this file through Safari and then open it on macOS 10.12.2. Your file may have been corrupted during the download process, or the download may have been interrupted. You may need to try a different browser.

Comment: Thanks Ralph, unfortunately I tried multiple times on multiple browsers (Firefox ESR 45.7.0, Safari 10.0.3, & Chrome 56.0.2924.87) & had no luck :(    I don't suppose you know of a command line prompt that can help me override this error on macOS? Based on your comment, it appears the program itself is fine, it's something that happened during download that messed it up.

Comment: I don't know of any command-line prompt that would help with this. Are you behind a corporate firewall? Some kind of security software may be standing in your way. If nothing else makes sense, you can open a Bluemix Support ticket at https://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport .

Comment: Thanks! I've logged a ticket @ ibm.biz/bluemixsupport